# My environment variable comes up undefined

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I'm not sure why my environment variable comes up undefined. This is the first time I am using environment variables and can not seem to figure out what the issue is,

My environment file is something like this:

```
# ANSIBLE MANAGED FILE, YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST!
PORT=3001
NODE_ENV=development

# PostgreSQL
MY_DATABASE_CLIENT: 'pg'
MY_DATABASE_HOST: '127.0.0.1'
```

and my model contains these two lines:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '/opt/eosapi/.env'});

console.log("ENV VARIABLE CHECK...",process.env.MY_DATABASE_CLIENT);
```

however whenever I run this file, I get:

> ENV VARIABLE CHECK... undefined

Could anyone point out the issue to me?

Comment: is your project inside `/opt/eosapi/`?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly yes /opt/eosapi, that's where I run my node plugin.js to start the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the absolute path

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

And then debug using

```
const result = require('dotenv').config()

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}

console.log(result.parsed)
```

Use proper assingment

```
# ANSIBLE MANAGED FILE, YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST!
PORT=3001
NODE_ENV=development

# PostgreSQL
MY_DATABASE_CLIENT='pg'       # <--------- must be =
MY_DATABASE_HOST='127.0.0.1'  # <--------- must be =
```

Comment: Hmm it shows upto NODE_ENV but nothing after that?!

Comment: Removed relative path

Comment: Yes path is removed. is it because the environment variables I have been given are using : instead of =?